# Is it possible to "hide" an image in a small div and show it when it expands?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am creating a div that expands when it clicked and it and so far it is 35px high and I wan't it to hold an image that's about 250px high and show when the div expands

I thought I could set the image as a background in a child div but it isn't working

This is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="banner">
    <div style="height:35px; line-height:30px; color:white;">Click to enlarge ></div>

    <div class="banner-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.banner {width: 100%; height:35px; background-color:red; cursor:pointer;}
.banner-content {width: 100%; background-color:blue; background-image: url("https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-8-5666133911797760.3-hp.gif");}
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".banner").click(function(){
        $(this).css('height', $(this).css('height') == "35px" ? "270px" : "35px");
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pt4jaL20/)

Comment: css media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to `toggle` a single css class, like `open`, then do the rest with just css. And don't forget to give the `.banner-content` a `height` too, otherwise it is not visible.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".banner").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("open")
    });
});
```

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 35px; 
  background-color: red; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.banner.open { 
  height: 270px; 
}
.banner.open .banner-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-8-5666133911797760.3-hp.gif");}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div style="height:35px; line-height:30px; color:white;">Click to enlarge ></div>
  <div class="banner-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide and show the "banner-content" according to the height of the "banner"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".banner").find(".banner-content").hide();
    $(".banner").click(function(){
        $(this).css('height', $(this).css('height') == "35px" ? "270px" : "35px");
        if($(this).css('height') == "35px")
            $(this).find(".banner-content").hide();
        else
        $(this).find(".banner-content").show();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pt4jaL20/1/